# How to automatically create a Date Stamp while monitoring specific Cells and Notes for changes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet at work that we use to track a variety of things, but I need to have a Cell (G1) updated with a Date Stamp as other Cells (H1:BA1) are updated, or if a Note on any of those Cells is created/updated.

Best I can find is [this](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/docs/sS6R1y-eQnQ/vrO70iAVAQAJ) or [that](https://cyberhacktivist.com/create-timestamp-google-sheets/), but they don't account for Notes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: No triggers for changes or edits in notes or comments.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for checking out my post. Unfortunately you can't have a timestamp created for notes, as far as I am aware.